# How to get distinct column data on the basis of latest date time from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, greatest-n-per-group

I have table  `login` with columns `id, username, logindate`.

Sample data looks like this:

```
{1, username1, logindate1}
{2, username2, logindate2}
{3, username1, logindate3}
{4, username2, logindate4}
```

and I want to get this result:

```
{1, username1, logindate1} 
{2, username2, logindate2}
```

Means latest logindate for distinct user.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from (
    select *,rn=row_number() over (partition by username order by logindate desc)
    from login
) x
where rn=1
order by username;
```